# How can I unignore the Feeds user?

Tags: support, chat, feed, ignored-users

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I un-ignore a user in chat?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146616/how-can-i-un-ignore-a-user-in-chat)

A while ago I put the Feeds user on chat.SO on ignore because he was annoying me. Now, however, it is too silent in all those chat rooms for me and I kinda miss him.

How can I apologize and make him come back?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is the same as for unblocking regular users.

Three simple steps:

[image]

Comment: 'Cept you gotta find him first when he disappears form the user list. ;)

Comment: Ignored users (real or bots) disappear from your prefs?

Comment: Now that you ask, he didn't appear even after unignoring him. Strange.

Comment: Confused. Yes, Feeds disappears from there if you un-ignore. If you want to ignore he/she/it, presumably you have one of his "objectionable" messages right there in front of you and you can directly click on the profile link.

Comment: Well, yea problem was that I've ignored him a couple of months ago. Somehow he disappeared from my user list so I couldn't simply click his profile and unignore him. For some reason he is still hiding though.

Comment: Well that sounds more like a bug.

Comment: Yup, I should  probably report it.

Answer (score 0):

To summon Feeds you have to find his chat user profile and simply click *"don't ignore this user"*.

<sub>Note: You can also just click on [Feeds](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/-2)' name here if you can't find him or something.</sub>