# How can I un-ignore a user in chat?

Tags: support, chat, ignored-users

I mistakenly used "ignore this user (everywhere)" in a chat room. How can I undo this?

Comment: I made a pretty big edit to your question. I assume this is what you were trying to ask? If not, just roll back my edit.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There are several ways to do this.

### Directly in the room

If the user is in a room with you (which is very likely if you just now ignored them), they'll not be totally hidden; their avatar in the user list in the top right has just shrunk:

[image: Tiny Tim]

If you click this small avatar, you can choose "don't ignore this user" in the resulting pop-up.

### On your profile

When you go to your own chat user profile and click the "prefs" tab, this will take you to something like this:

[image: ignored user in profile]

(yours won't say "balpha", obviously). It shows a list of all users you're ignoring; just click the "X" on a user card to unignore.

### On their profile

Go to the main chat page for your particular SO/SE site. For example http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/

At the very top you will find a link to the users.

[image]

Instead of "online" or "active", select the "all" tab. If you know the particular user's name, you can then filter users until you see the particular user you've ignored.

[image: Do I think that's funny? Why yes I do]

Clicking on this user's name will reveal a page specific to this user and a "don't ignore this user" button as illustrated below.

[image]

Clicking this will remove the user from your list of ignored users.

Comment: I have expanded your answer slightly :) While your answer is correct, it's actually the most complicated way.

Comment: @balpha I object to your entirely reasonable and constructive edit. Unnecessarily obscure solutions are the way forward! But well, I won't get into a rollback war with a mod I guess. ;) Thanks.